# Hide header and footer of article in Joomla 3.8

Tags: joomla3.0, article

I am new to Joomla. I created an article. I tried to hide the header and footer section of article.

How to hide the header and footer of articles?

Answer (score 1):

i found answer.
go to menus > select the menu item in which you want to hide the title of the article. 
then go to "options" tab and set the "Show Title" > Hide and save it.